# Как после dialog обновить данные в recyclerview?

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-dialog, recyclerviewadapter

есть елемент в recyclerview, на которм кнопка его меню
после выбора edit из меню открывается один диалог который изменяет елемент в recyclerview.
прикол в том что не знаю как визульно обновить recyclerview из диалога.
пока что метод notifyDataSetChanged(); тупо вынес в опцию details которя в меню.

код адаптера

```
public class ExampleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExampleAdapter.ExampleViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<Order> singolo_ordine;
    private static Context context;


    public static class ExampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView mImageView;    public ImageView m_status_order; public ImageView m_photo_icon; public ImageView m_menu_order;

        public TextView mTextView1;     public TextView m_name_order;
        public TextView mTextView2;     public TextView m_start_time_order;




        public ExampleViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);    m_status_order=itemView.findViewById(R.id.status_order); m_photo_icon=itemView.findViewById(R.id.photo_icon); m_menu_order=itemView.findViewById(R.id.menu_order);
            mTextView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);     m_name_order=itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_order);
            mTextView2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);    m_start_time_order=itemView.findViewById(R.id.start_time_order);
            TextView marqueeText1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_order);
            marqueeText1.setSelected(true);


            itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "CLICK LUNGO VERRA' DISATTIVATO E BASTA =)=)=)=) " + getAdapterPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    return false;
                }
            });


        }
    }

    public ExampleAdapter(ArrayList<Order> esempio_ordine) {
        singolo_ordine = esempio_ordine;
    }

    @Override
    public ExampleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.order_fragment, parent, false);
        ExampleViewHolder evh = new ExampleViewHolder(v);






        context=parent.getContext();
        return evh;

    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ExampleViewHolder holder, final int position) {


        holder.m_menu_order.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Display option menu
                Context wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.myListPopupWindow);
                PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(wrapper, holder.m_menu_order);
               // PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(context, holder.m_menu_order);
                popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.order_menu);
                popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.edit:
                            Mod_order mod_order=new Mod_order(singolo_ordine,holder.getAdapterPosition());
                            mod_order.showDialog((Activity) context);
                                notifyDataSetChanged();
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Condiviso", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                break;
                            case R.id.details:
                             
                                notifyDataSetChanged();

                                break;
                            case R.id.delete:
                                //Delete item
                                singolo_ordine.remove(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                               // notifyDataSetChanged();
                                notifyItemRemoved(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                popupMenu.show();

            }
        });




        Order currentItem = singolo_ordine.get(position);


        holder.m_start_time_order.setText(currentItem.get_data_inizio());
        holder.m_name_order.setText(currentItem.get_name());
        if(currentItem.get_stato()==2)
        {
            holder.m_status_order.setImageResource(R.drawable.processing);
            RotateAnimation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(359f, 0,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

            rotateAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
            rotateAnimation.setDuration(5000);
            rotateAnimation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);

            holder.m_status_order.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
            holder.m_status_order.setHasTransientState(true);
        }
        if(currentItem.get_stato()==1) holder.m_status_order.setImageResource(R.drawable.done);
        if(currentItem.get_stato()==0) holder.m_status_order.setImageResource(R.drawable.cancelled);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return singolo_ordine.size();
    }
}
```

код класа диалога

```
public class Mod_order {
int position;
ArrayList<Order> ordine;
Mod_order(ArrayList<Order> esempio_ordine, int set_position){
    this.position=set_position;
    this.ordine=esempio_ordine;
}
        public void showDialog(final Activity activity) {

            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.edit_order);
            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

            final Button mDialogNo = dialog.findViewById(R.id.delete_order);
            final EditText edit= dialog.findViewById(R.id.name_order_edit_text);
            final EditText edit_comment=dialog.findViewById(R.id.edit_comment);




            mDialogNo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {



                    dialog.dismiss();

                }
            });

            final Button mDialogOk = dialog.findViewById(R.id.save_order);
            mDialogOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


Order ordine_es;
ordine_es=ordine.get(position);
ordine_es.set_name(String.valueOf(edit.getText()));
ordine.remove(position);
ordine.add(position,ordine_es);


                }});

            dialog.show();





        }
    }
```

это моё первое приложение и первый опыт программирования на java
так что код сто процентов не из лучших

Comment: Так и сделал! Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А вы и не должны это обновлять из диалога. В диалоге должен быть какой-то листенер (интерфейс по типу OnItemClickListener) который будет торчать наружу и задаваться либо в конструкторе либо в отдельном методе.

А реализация этого интерфейса будет в активити/фрагменте. Оттуда вы и вызовите обновление своего адаптера